# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter' after

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been recently attempting to try out some minor game development with Python 3.9 and have been running into some problems. For some reason, Python does not recognize that I have tkinter installed.
From what I have seen online, a big fix is to make sure the path variables are set up correctly. I have already added it to my env variables but that has not seemed to fix anything.

[image: Windows Env Variables]

I also know I have it installed, as I see it here in my Python site-packages folder.

[image: Python Site Packages]

At this point, I am stumped. I do have the import as tkinter as well and not Tkinter.
The only thing I can think of now is totally uninstalling Python but I would prefer not to do that if there are any other options.

Here is the code:

```py
import math
import random
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class cube(object):
    rows = 20
    w = 500
```

I am using Windows 10 and VSCode as well.
Anything helps and thanks!

Comment: `tkinter` isn't in `side-packages`. Also it looks like you have a library installed called `tk` - that is not `tkinter`. How did you install `python`?

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm not entirely sure as I did it a lil while back, but if memory serves me correctly I did it through Pythons website.

Comment: The default python installation from python's official website should install `tkinter` by default. Check if one of these 2 folders exists: "C:/Python39/Lib/tkinter/" or "C:/Python39/tkinter/".

Comment: @TheLizzard Looks like neither of those 2 folders exist. I'm guessing that means I screwed up Pythons installation. Does that mean I will have to uninstall and then reinstall?

Comment: You can try that but make sure that `tkinter` is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I somehow screwed up my Python installation. Completely removing it from my system and reinstalling seemed to fix all of my issues.